# Execute empty nested sql script

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I have a SQL*Plus script that contains several nested scipts, following this schema:

```
@Script1;
@Script2;
@Script3;
```

My problem is some of the nested script could be empty,they exist but are blank (0kb size), which cause an error when I execute the main script.

I can not add comments to the scripts since they are generated programatically.

Is there any way to skip this error?

Comment: What error do you get? There should be no problem doing what you describe (even with the unnecessary trailing `;`).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure the file *exists*?

Comment: Completely sure, this is the error I got when I run the script with Toad and reach the first line with an empty .sql:
"Unable to read D:\TALEND_V5_2_1\Studio\out\Indicadores\MIDE_METAS.sql"
And just happens with empties .sql,

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have used Toad to find the problem, with SQL*PLUS it just stops when reaches the mentioned line.

Comment: 'Just stopped' means it waits at a prompt? Does your master script have an `exit`, or is expecting the last child script to include that?

Comment: I finally found the problem.
The SQL*plus console showed just a number at the end which resulted to be a line number, the script execution was hanged at the end of last script with a routine, just adding a "\" at the end of scripts after "end;" for cleaning the buffer, solved the problem, thank you very much.